# Accessing data using Pillow corrupts it on response in Django Rest Framework (The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library, django-serializer

I want to extract the **format** and **mode** parameter from the uploaded image within the Serializer and dynamically update my fields. Here is the code ...

```
class ImageDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.ImageData
    exclude = ['height','width']
```

And in my view

```
    serializer = serializer(data=request.data,partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    obj = serializer.save(user=request.user,extension="PNG",image_type="RGB")     
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This works perfectly. I am sending my **InMemeoryUploadedFile** instance as my data and the serializer does its job saving it to the database. However, I would like to determine the extension and image_type automatically using the Pillow library.
This is what I have tried so far ...

```
class ImageDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(ImageDataSerializer,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    myimage = self.initial_data['data']
    with Image.open(myimage) as myimage:
        self.fields['extension'].initial = myimage.format
        self.fields['image_type'].initial = myimage.mode
    # Update the extension and image_type initial values
class Meta:
    model = models.ImageData
    exclude = ['height','width']
```

What happens is my image file get corrupted and in the response I am getting the message **"Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."**
I have also tried determining the extension and mode within the view and pass it to request.data dictionary but accessing the image file once using Pillow.Image.open() is later corrupting it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the **cursor**. 
After opening the file using Pillow once you need to reset the cursor to the beginning of the file for future usage by Django. Below is fully working code.

```
class ImageDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    data = kwargs.get("data",None)
    img = data.get("data",None)
    with Image.open(img) as myimage:
        data['extension'] = myimage.format
        data['image_type'] = myimage.mode

    img.seek(0)       
    super(ImageDataSerializer,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)



class Meta:
    model = models.ImageData
    exclude = ['height','width']
    read_only_fields = ['user']
```

img.seek(0) Resets the cursor to the beginning of the file